# Connecting geo coordinate points by lines

Tags: maps, draw, latitude-longitude, lines, points

I have a set of Geo coordinate points with lat/lon values . I have plotted the points on a map. I want to connect the points by lines. I have tried the Points to Line tool in GIS but it just creates a polygon. I want to draw lines between the from(lon/lat) and to(lon/lat) coordinate points in this data set. Is there a simple way to do it? Here is some sample data.

```
From_Lon   From_Lat   To_Lon   To_Lat
80.869178 16.357785   78.404167 17.383333
80.159683 12.981479   80.096817 12.992996
80.159412 12.981387   80.159422 12.981405
80.224847 12.975094   78.509808 17.441822
80.27     13.0839     78.509583 17.441693
78.4346   17.5088     80.203153 13.130134
80.201632 13.128197   80.201642 13.128202
80.201661 13.128212   80.037924 12.819227
80.021806 12.783412   80.168016 12.92074
```